# Laravel + GuzzleHTTP no response data?

Tags: json, laravel, post, guzzle

I'm querying my API using guzzle.

```
$client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('xxxxxx',
            array(
                'headers' => array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'),
                'json'=> array(
                    "type" => 0,
                    [...]
                )
            )
        );

        //$response = json_decode($response);

        dd($response->getBody());
```

This should output me something like this:

```
{
  "returnCode": 0,
  "success": true
}
```

but instead I get something else.

```
Stream {#230 ▼
  -stream: stream resource @12 ▼
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

Can anyonee help me or tell me what i did wrong? I want to send raw post data and also get raw post data afterwards I then want to save (for example in a db).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getBody()
```

returns a streaminterface. You want to get the content of that stream, so:

```
$response->getBody()->getContents();
```

is what you're searching for

**Note**

According to the docs, you can also cast the streaminterface to a string, but I've had varying results. `getContents()` always does what it needs to do, so that's my go to solution.

Comment: This perfect, works how it should. The only thing that bothers me that it return me the json object as a string.  `"{"returnCode":0,"success":true}"`. Can i convert that somehow?

Comment: If you mean you want your JSON to be a string, it already is. If you want to make that string a php object, simply do `json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents())`